# Separability of differentiable functions

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, banach-algebras, separable-spaces

Is the Banach space $ (C_0^1(0,T),\|\cdot\|_{C^1})$ separable?

We define
$
C_0^1(a,b):=\{f\in C_0(a,b):\ f'\in C_0(a,b)\},
$
where $C_0(a,b)$ is the space of real-valued continuous functions on $[a,b]\subset \mathbb R$ such that $f(a)=f(b)=0$, $\|f\|_{C^1} :=\|f\|_\infty+\|f'\|_\infty$, where $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ is the supremum norm and $f'$ denotes the first derivative of $f$.

Comment: Trigonometric polynomials (of period $T$) with rational coefficients are dense.

Comment: Do you know about mollifiers? That would help here.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich : How to guarantee that $f'(a)=f'(b)=0$ for a choice of a trigonometric polynomial $f$ satisfying $f(a)=f(b)=0$?

Comment: @Ton I missed that condition, sorry. Fix a sequence of functions $f_n$ with $f_n(a)=f_n(b)=f_n'(a)=f_n'(b)=0$, such that $0\le f_n\le1$ and $f_n=1$ on $[a+1/n,b-1/n]$. Then the functions of the form $f_n(t)p(t)$ where $p$ is a trigonometric polynomial with rational coefficients are dense.